# CUDA: Compilation failure on large struct >4GB

Tags: cuda

I have a rather large struct in my CUDA code

```
struct cDevData {
    ~5GB worth of stuff ...
};
```

I allocate the space required to hold that structure during system setup with cudaMalloc because windows limits static code and data to 2GB. Annoying, but Fine. Obviously I'm compiling a 64bit application, but when I do I get the following error for the Debug configuration:

```
ptxas C : /Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_0000123c_00000000-4_kernel.ptx, line 2897; error : Value out of range for type .b32
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

And curiously a different one for Release configuration:

```
error C2089: 'cDevData' : 'struct' too large
```

It only started happening when I increased the size of this structure over 4GB.
I've also tried to compile a 32bit application just to check and I get a different (expected) error `class is too large`.
What's going on, and is there a way around it?

System: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, CUDA toolkit 8.0, GPU = Titan.

Comment: without some actual code to compile, disassemble and study, I doubt anyone can provide an answer beyond your initial diagnosis, i.e. the structure is too large.

Comment: Hello, remember that you must provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you expect some help from SO users.

Comment: How about accepting it is just too large and splitting it up? It's not like you'll be able to keep many of them around anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of two bugs - one in NVCC and another in VS2012. From NVIDIA's response:

The error generated in the Release configuration "error C2089: 'cDevData' : 'struct' too large" is coming from the host compiler. So this issue is due to a limitation in the host compiler on Windows. We will fix the other issue exposed in Debug configuration. However, even after the fix, the compilation will fail on Windows due to the host compiler limitation.

I don't know if this issue is fixed in VS2015 or later. 
In the meanwhile I circumvented the problem(s) through an industrious use of `boost::mpl` and some macros, to retain struct-like semantics (accessing fields by names, complex field types like multi-dimensional arrays retain their dimensions, etc). Thus at the end my code required minimal changes (changing field deref op `->` into a macro, and replacing `sizeof(cDevData)` with another macro).